# How do I add the title of a list item to a custom action URL?

Tags: query-string

I'm trying to build a custom action button that links to a page with a query string URL.

[image]

I've tried "?Project={ItemTitle} but that doesn't work.

I can get the ID by adding "?Project={ItemId}" but how can I get the item title?

Answer (score 0):

The replaceable variables are very limited. The only way I was able to do something similar was to use a really long javascript snip that would grab the info from the page. That text can be pretty long - hard to format but it can be done. Here's a description of how I added a mailto item to a custom action - I was able to get the title by diving into the dom:

javascript:window.location='mailto:?subject='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById({SelectedItemId}).firstChild.innerHTML)+'&body='+encodeURIComponent('\n\nTitle: '+document.getElementById({SelectedItemId}).firstChild.innerHTML+'\n')+encodeURIComponent('Link: <'+document.getElementById({SelectedItemId}).firstChild.getAttribute('href')+'>');